# How can i get top 15 occurrences in an array and use each value to fetch data from mysql database?

Tags: arrays, codeigniter

I am currently working on a project (A music website) with PHP Codeigniter. I want to fetch top 15 songs by number of downloads. To my knowledge, I got all unique ID's out ranging from highest to least. But now, I want to use each of these unique ID's to fetch data from another table in the database.

I have tried using for loop; but it seems to only return one of the rows which happens to be the first and highest number of occurrence in the array. The code below echo's the ID's but how can I use each of those ID's to fetch data.

```
function top15(){
            $this->db->select('musiccode');
            $result=$this->db->get('downloads');
            $query = $result->result_array();
            $downloads = array();
            if(!empty($query)) {
                   foreach($query as $row)
                   {
                     $musiccode[] = $row['musiccode'];
                   }

                $mode = array_count_values($musiccode);
                arsort($mode);
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($mode as $field => $number) {
                    $i++;
                    echo $field." occured ". $number." times <br>";
                    if ($i == 15) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

```
for ($b=0; $b < count($field); $b++) { 
 $this->db->where(array('track_musiccode'=> $field));
 $field = $this->db->get('tracks');
 return $field->result_array();
}
```

The code above only produce one row for me. I expect to have  more than one and according to the number of ID's in the array. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For a single column condition, you could use [where_in()](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/query_builder.html?highlight=where_in#CI_DB_query_builder::where_in) instead and drop the `for` loop :

```php
 $this->db->where_in('track_musiccode', $field);
 $field = $this->db->get('tracks');
 return $field->result_array();
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but it still returns the first element. I tried counting the array and it returned 1 which is that first one. If you have a different approach to what I want to do, please help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Finally i did it. Incase if anyone needs it. this works just fine

```
function top15(){
        $this->db->where('d_month', date('m'));
        $this->db->select('musiccode');
        $result=$this->db->get('downloads');
        $query = $result->result_array();
        $downloads = array();
        if(!empty($query)) {
           foreach($query as $row){
                $musiccode[] = $row['musiccode'];
           }    
                $res='';
                $count=array_count_values($musiccode);
                arsort($count);
                $keys=array_keys($count);
                for ($i=0; $i < count($keys); $i++) { 
                    $res[] .= "$keys[$i]";
                }
                $this->db->where_in('track_musiccode', $res);
                return $this->db->get('tracks')->result_array();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

And I got this too. If I wasn't going to count occurrences but just iterate the number of downloads which is far more better than counting in other not to over populate the database and make your website work slowly.

```
    function top15(){
        $tracks = '';
        $this->db->group_by('counter');
        $result=$this->db->get('downloads');
        $query = $result->result_array();
        $counter = '';
        $fields = '';
        if(!empty($query)) {
            foreach($query as $row) {
                $counter[] = $row['counter'];   
            }
            rsort($counter); 
            for ($i=0; $i<=15; $i++) {
                $this->db->where('downloads.counter', $counter[$i]);
                $this->db->join('tracks', 'tracks.musicid = downloads.musicid');
                $fields[] = $this->db->get('downloads')->row_array();
            }
            return $fields;
        }
    }
```

Enjoy...